# Two queries are using the same type with different fields in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I'm pretty new to GraphQL and Apollo Client.

At the moment my GraphQL API has a query of this type:

```
type Directory {
  name: String
  id: String
  parentId: String
  files: [PaginatedFiles]
  children: [Directory]
  ...
}
```

Initially, I had one query for fetching all the fields from the type above, but after a while, I decided to implement infinity scroll (fetches + 20 files every time user scrolls the page) for files (because sometimes there are up to 1000 files in the directory).

In order to use the `fetchMore` feature of Apollo hooks we decided to have 2 queries, that use the same type (Directory), but have different fields:

```
query getDirectory($id: String!) {
  directory(id: $id) {
    name
    id
    parentId
    children
  }
}

query getDirectoryFiles($directoryId: String!, $after: String) {
  directory(id: $directoryId) {
    files(after: $after) {
      after
      items {
        ...FileBaseFields
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, graphql-codegen creates the hooks for me, so I'm using them like so:

```
const [fetchDirectory, { loading: directoryLoading, data: directory }] = 
  useFetchDirectoryLazyQuery()

const [fetchDirectoryFiles, {
  loading: directoryFilesLoading,
  data: directoryFiles,
  fetchMore,
}] = useFetchDirectoryFilesLazyQuery()
```

With such an approach I'm able to use `fetchMore`, providing variables to it ("directoryId" and "after").

Is it ok to have two queries, that use one Type, or should I create two separate types (handlers)?

Comment: it's ok, apollo [as normalizing cache] will connect props from both directory entries [by id] ... insert `debugger` in code, explore apollo client cache entries